# How i can generate login link with FishStick API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

The library i used https://www.npmjs.com/package/fortnite-api-manager
I know that it's possible to generate login link with only one command with using discord.js but as you can see it requires 3 values.

```
let accountId = 'Your Account Id'
let deviceId = 'Your Device Id'
let secret = 'Your Secret'

let config = {
  'accountId':accountId,
  'deviceId':deviceId,
  'secret':secret
};
```

I need to login in account and get needed stats.

So, how to generate login link without account, device ids and secret?

Comment: Perhaps you might want to use the `fnbr` package

Comment: Also look at the docs at https://fnbr.js.org/#/docs

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js)?